# Button located under tabitem (within tabcontrol) but the handler needs to be in the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a main windows, which contains some controls including a tabcontrol. The tab control itself has multiple tabitems. Each tab item has a unique design. When the user clicks a button within one of the tab items, I want the event handler to be within the main window's .cs file. I cant figure out a way to do that, can any one enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax may not be perfect, but what about this:

```
public interface ITabControlWithNotifications
{
    void OnButtonClicked(...);
}

public sealed class TabControlWithNotifications : TabControl, ITabControlWithNotifications
{
    public void OnButtonClicked(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public sealed class TabPageWithNotifications : TabPage
{
    private readonly ITabControlWithNotifications parentTabControl;

    public TabPageWithNotifications(ITabControlWithNotifications tabControlWithNotifications)
    {
        this.parentTabControl = tabControlWithNotifications;
        this.InitialzeComponents();
    }

    ... ClickEventHandler(...)
    {
        this.parentTabControl.OnButtonClicked(...);
    }
}

public sealed class TabControlFactory
{
    public void Build()
    {
        var parentTabControl = new TabControlWithNotifications();
        var tabPage1 = new TabPageWithNotifications(parentTabControl);
        var tabPage2 = new TabPageWithNotifications(parentTabControl);
        var tabPage3 = new TabPageWithNotifications(parentTabControl);
        parentTabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage1);
        parentTabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage2);
        parentTabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage3);
    }
}
```